# Include external css/js file into html page

Tags: javascript, css, href

I'm trying to **link manually** my CSS and Javascript files to my HTML scripts, but I've never really done it with files **from a different folder**/directory. This is what I have so far:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Desktop/Script/CSS/tempeststyle.css"/>
<link rel=script" type="text/javascript" href="/Desktop/Script/Javascript/tempestscript.js"/>
```

I've read from a few sources that you don't have to start all the way at `C:/Users` or whatever the case may be for different systems, but I'm not sure if these links are acceptable the way they are (i.e., them starting at "/Desktop"). The files are in separate folders within the same folder on the desktop. So how to include them **the best way**? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using web-server than these links are not acceptable

Comment: The "link" is a url. If you can't see it though the web browser then it won't work. You will need to put your css/js into a folder in your web site, not the desktop

Comment: The second one should use `<script>` tag, not `<link>`.

Comment: Also, use `<script>` instead of `<link>` for including JS.

Comment: Thank you @ManojKumar fuyushimoya.

Comment: Also, thank you, @Liam. I'll read about that. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add scripts from local path you can use a relative path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/tempeststyle.css"/>
```

or relative path from your web root folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/CSS/tempeststyle.css"/>
```

or filesystem absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Path/To/Scripts/styles/CSS/tempeststyle.css"/>
```

It is rather better if you use an absolute path from your web server:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/styles/CSS/tempeststyle.css"/>
```

Comment: Be careful with the `file://` this looks for the file on the browser(client) **not the server**! So unless the person browsing your site has this file locally (which is very unlikely 99% of the time) they will not get the relevant css/js. Typically this would not be used.

Comment: Absolutely right @Liam, the absolute filesystem path has been added for completeness, but typically is unusefull.

Comment: Would you guys be able to elaborate a bit on how to find/create the absolute path from a webserver, or maybe point me somewhere that would help?