# How do I properly locally link Jquery/Bootstrap and scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a while I've been trying to figure out how to properly reference jQuery and Bootstrap locally. Noticed that my navbar dropdown menu wasn't working. Couldn't figure out why and decided to paste the CDN links for both jQuery and Bootstrap and it worked just as anticipated:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
   <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

   <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default bg-primary">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--logo-->
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">WebsiteBrand</a>
            </div>
            <!--navbar items-->
            <div>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <!--dropdown-->
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
                     <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my header file. It's the same place I had put the CDN links. Sorry if this is a silly question, but after looking around for such a long time I decided to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include external css/js file into html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478338/include-external-css-js-file-into-html-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ordering of file linking & tagging should be

```
 <head>
   <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

   <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
```

You missed **.js** text in `bootstrap.min.js`

Considering **folder structure** as below

- index.html
- `css` folder

  - bootstrap.css
  - bootstrap-theme.css
- `js` folder

  - jquery-3.2.1.min.js
  - bootstrap.min.js
  - script.js

Updating answer as the question being updated

**Bootstrap v3**

Here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/9zgddjjf/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default bg-primary">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <!--logo-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">WebsiteBrand</a>
    </div>
    <!--navbar items-->
    <div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <!--dropdown-->
          <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
             <span class="caret"></span></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

**Bootstrap v4**

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/9zgddjjf/2/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
   <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">WebsiteBrand</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Page 1
         <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a  class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1-1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1-2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1-3</a>
         </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks for making everything look so nice( im not being sarcastic, wanted to point that out so i don't come across rude) i fixed the issue on my side before copying and pasting what you posted. this doesnt seem to have fixed my issue that using the cdn fixes. any functionality to my drop-down menu doesnt work until i use the cdn for both jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: @who885 ... are you getting any error in browser console?? Please share your `HTML` code, will definitely help you out...

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g6no5a this is the output to my console. i don't understand what it means. but it points to the line i link my <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />.

Comment: You are missing the tether.js library file. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" ></script>`.

Comment: I have updated the answer as well. Check the ordering of the files also.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g6nrpx - it seems like i was still getting an error. assuming it was possibly the cdn for tether being down i searched for another one.  ill look for another tether cdn in the meantime.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap v3 or bootstrap v4?

Comment: i am using bootstrap v4.

Comment: this works when i use a cdn. but not when i try to locally link bootstrap, jquery :/ i might just go back to using a cdn at this rate. i wanted to be able to work on this while offline, might not be able to at this rate.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g6nyf4 unfortunately it seems like things get weird and buggy. this is using the updated header and the code you contributed. if it helps im using the latest jquery. this works fine in fiddle but not for me.

Comment: @who885... Your code is written belongs to `bootstrap v3` & you are trying to use `bootstrap v4` library. Do you think it will work. That's why I told you to **check the updated answer**. I changed the `HTML` code a bit, please copy the code.

Comment: For using your application offline, please open `cdn` links in `browser` & **copy entire code & save it** in your local with proper name.

Comment: iv seem to have gotten it to work. i apologize for not seeing the code from earlier.  this totally fixes my issue with bootstrap! theres just one issue with it not being able to fetch bootstrap-theme.js and my js file. but i will figure that out myself. thank you so much. im very new to learning to program and this was helpful.

Comment: @who885.. That's ok... I appreciate your learning nature. Please accept the answer..